# internalDate or Date in gmail api - objective-c library

Tags: objective-c, gmail-api

How could I get the "internalDate" while use gmail api objective-c library? I understand the 'internalDate' is available while I directly use gmail restful api.

Since GTLGmailMessage doesn't have internalDate property, I can't directly use it.

I also tried to use 'Date' in GTLGmailMessagePart's headers. The returned value is something like 'Fri, 27 Mar 2015 17:18:08 +0000'
What's the best way to format this to NSDate?

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused, because I googled `GTLGmailMessage` and found [`GTLGmailMessage.h`](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client/blob/master/Source/Services/Gmail/Generated/GTLGmailMessage.h#L60), which defines an `internalDate` property.

Comment: Thanks. I think the problem is that I used this cocoapods package (https://cocoapods.org/pods/Google-API-Client) to manage my gmail api objective-c lib. Apparently I am not getting the latest gmail objective-c lib.

Comment: Based from this example, [GTLGmailMessage](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client/blob/8c275b7da75b90688acf80f7fa53c1ba9403ca02/Source/Services/Gmail/Generated/GTLGmailMessage.m) have internal property. `internalDate` has a value of `long` wherein for normal SMTP-received email, this represents the time the message was originally accepted by Google, which is more reliable than the `Date` header. However, for API-migrated mail, it can be configured by client to be based on the `Date` header.

Comment: @Liangjun were you able to figure this out? Even I am using the Cocoapod, but not getting the property.

Comment: @footyapps27 the Cocoapods of Google API Client is not updated since 2015. I think it's better to use the official guide.

Comment: @Liangjun I answered to your question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has officially released the pods for using the GMail API. This is in sync with the development taking place in their Github account.

The pod details can be found [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client/blob/master/GoogleAPIClient.podspec)

There is one issue for with `GTMOAuthViewController` not found. I have already raised the issue to them.

Thus you can now update your `podspec` as mentioned below & everything should work as expected.

```
pod 'GoogleAPIClient'
pod 'GoogleAPIClient/Gmail’
```

*P.S - With this update, you will be able to access the `internalDate`.*